# Plotly Python Irregular behaviour on image export

Tags: python, azure-functions, plotly-python

When exporting figures as .png on Python Plotly (5.11.0) and Kaleido (0.1.*) locally, everything works fine.

The figure I am trying to export is a simple 2-lines plot with a third line (that is filled, creating an area plot)

However, when doing the exact same operation through Azure functions it doesn't work as expected, only the grey area plot is exported in the figure.

This is basically the code I am using:

```
fig = px.line(df_unpivot[df_unpivot['column name']!='var_2'], x = 'index_series', y ='yName', color= 'Data type', labels={
                     "index_series": "Period",
            
                 })
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['index_series'], y=df['var_2'], line_color='grey', mode = 'lines', name= 'Variable name', fill='tozeroy'))

logging.info (fig)

logging.info('dataframe head - {}'.format(df.head()))
logging.info('dataframe head - {}'.format(df_unpivot.head()))
logging.info ('Created the chart, exporting to sharepoint')
#fig.show()
local_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
local_dir = os.path.abspath(local_path)
path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'imagem.png')
fig.write_image(path, validate = True)
with open(path, 'rb') as content_file:
    file_content = content_file.read()
```

I have also tried creating the plot using other techniques (such as `px.area`) but it doesn't produce different results. I have also tried creating the image through `img_bytes = fig.to_image(format="png", scale = 1)`, but the behaviour is always the same (works locally but not on Azure).

This is what it exports when running through azure function:

[image: erroneous plot]

This is what I get running the same script locally:

[image: correct plot]

At first I suspected that the figure wasn't being properly produced by Plotly, but after analyzing the fig object (from the log) I saw that it was exactly the same in Azure and locally.

So I suspected that it was  related with the image export (tried several things such as changing the format, scale, etc.) but it still didn't work.

Reducing the amount of data by selecting only a portion of the rows (using `df.iloc`) produced a plot with 3 lines up to a certain number of rows, at which the weird behaviour starts to happen. So I think it can be related to a memory restriction on the Kaleido export. Exporting the scatter line without the fill also results in the mentioned behaviour.

I have searched a lot and didn't find this issue reported anywhere.